# Magento 2.2.7 Order sales report Shows empty results

Tags: magento2.2.7

If I select Date Used as Order Created it show me

```
We couldn't find any records.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To refresh report statistics:
>
> 1. On the Admin sidebar, tap Reports. Then under Statistics, choose Refresh Statistics.
> 2. In the list, mark the checkbox of each report to be refreshed.
> 3. Set the Actions control to one of the following: Refresh Lifetime Statistics Refresh Statistics for the Last Day
> 4. When complete, tap  Submit .

[image]

Comment: yes I also just discovered it.

Comment: yes that's why accepted you answer

Answer (score 0):

Option on top of the grid from where you can slect:

[image]